# Conditionally render firebase data in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Goal**: Render all of the documents in my firestore **that have** a `status: false`

Here is my **document structure**:

```
Status: false
Artist: Pablo Picasso
Medium: Oil Painting
```

And here is the code that loops through the data in firestore...

```js
function Feed() {
  const [artworks, setArtworks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("artworks").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setArtworks(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="artwork__feed">
        {artworks.map((artwork) => (
          <FeedCard
            artist={artwork.artist}
            medium={artwork.medium}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any ideas on how to loop through firebase and only render the data that has `status: false` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to [add a filter](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#simple_queries) to the query to find only the documents you want to show.

```
db.collection("artworks").where("Status", "==", false).onSnapshot(...)
```

Comment: And thanks for the documentation, still a bit new to all of this! You've helped me so much! Thanks!

Comment: Good to know.  On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and accept helpful answers using the buttons to the left of the answer.

Comment: Great! I tried to upvote but I received this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Thanks anyway!

Comment: You should be able to use the checkbox to accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Just clicked the check button, all set!